# unable to add a range to a tag using sh.addTagRange command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6

Have setup a 4 node test shard cluster:

- 1- mongos
- 1- config server
- 2- shard nodes hosting 1 shard each for a collection.

Cluster is working perfectly, but when trying to run the following command:

```
mongos> sh.addTagRange("HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository", { ShardMapId: "7" }, { ShardMapId: "11" }, "NRT")

 "errmsg" : "min: { ShardMapId: \"7\" } should be less than max: { ShardMapId: \"11\" }",
        "code" : 9,
        "codeName" : "FailedToParse",
```

Below is the shard status output:

```
databases:
        {  "_id" : "HTMLDumps",  "primary" : "shard0001",  "partitioned" : true }
                HTMLDumps.HTMLRepository
                        shard key: { "ShardMapId" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard0000       2
                                shard0001       2
                        { "ShardMapId" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "ShardMapId" : "" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(3, 1)
                        { "ShardMapId" : "" } -->> { "ShardMapId" : "1" } on : shard0001 Timestamp(1, 2) jumbo
                        { "ShardMapId" : "1" } -->> { "ShardMapId" : "7" } on : shard0000 Timestamp(2, 0)
                        { "ShardMapId" : "7" } -->> { "ShardMapId" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(3, 0)
```

### tag: NYC  { "ShardMapId" : "1" } -->> { "ShardMapId" : "7" }

### What am I missing?

Complete sh.status output: 
[image: sh.Status output]

Answer (score 0):

Shard key zone (tag) ranges require specifying `minimum` and `maximum` bounds for a range of shard key values.

Since your shard key values are currently strings, they will be [compared using binary order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#strings) rather than numerical order. The error message is correctly indicating that a minimum value of "7" (string) is not less than a value of "11" (string). For example, given the strings "1", "7", and "11" the expected ascending sort outcome using a binary string comparison is "1", "11", and "7". This is roughly [alphabetical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order), but more specifically strings in MongoDB are stored as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) bytes.

As you are intending on using zone sharding, for this test deployment it would be better to have numeric shard key values so you can use the range of 1-7 for your zone. You could remove and replace existing documents or just add more with the desired shard key values.

I assume you aren't concerned about the cardinality of your shard key for a test cluster, but for a real deployment you may want to [choose a more appropriate shard key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#sharding-shard-key-selection) if `ShardMapId` will only have a small range of values.

Note: tag-aware sharding was succeeded by [Zone sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/) in MongoDB 3.4. The `sh.addTagRange()` shell helper has been aliased to the modern equivalent of [`sh.updateZoneKeyRange()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.updateZoneKeyRange/#sh.updateZoneKeyRange), but I would recommend using the newer helpers to be safe. You should also ensure that your shell `version()` matches your server `db.version()`.